# WFS filter encoding with multi word values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wfs

I want to create a layer with WFS in QGIS, and filter out some objects with a filter encoding. My problem is that if I try to filter out based on a attribute value with two or more words in it, I get no results. I have tried the same url and FE in an web browser, there i do get results.

Does anyone know how to fiks this?

Here is an example that gives result in web browser, but not in QGIS:

```
url = "http://wfs.geonorge.no/skwms1/wfs.tilgjengelighet_tettsted?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&srsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4258&typeNames=app:TettstedInngangBygg&"

FE = "FILTER=<fes:Filter><fes:PropertyIsEqualTo><fes:ValueReference>app:tilgjengvurderingRulleAuto</fes:ValueReference><fes:Literal>Delvis tilgjengelig</fes:Literal></fes:PropertyIsEqualTo></fes:Filter>"

layer = QgsVectorLayer(url + FE, "test", "ogr")

print(layer.isValid())
```

The value in this examble is "Delvis tilgjengelig", if it is changed to the singel word "Tilgjengelig", it works in QGIS

Comment: Shouldn't the space in the value be URL encoded?

Comment: That does indeed work, thank you!
I am also having trouble with values that starts with "<", I have tried to use urllib on it, but it doesn't help. Do you know anything about that?